# File descriptors and pipe in C

Tags: c, linux, pipe, file-descriptor

I have a basic pipe in c, I have sent an integer to child process, the child process increase this number with 1 and will send back to parent process. 
My question is: What is happening if I close the write file descriptor right after write function ? The program will displayed `1` (the correct output is `2`)

```
int main(){

    int p[2];

    pipe(p);

    int n=1;
    write(p[1], &n, sizeof(int));
    close(p[1]); // don't work => the output is 1

    if(fork() == 0) {
            read(p[0], &n, sizeof(int));
            n = n + 1;
            write(p[1], &n, sizeof(int));
            close(p[1]);
            close(p[0]);
            exit(0);
    }
    wait(0);
    read(p[0], &n, sizeof(int));
    close(p[0]);
    //close(p[1]);  works => the output is 2

    printf("%d\n", n);
    return 1;

}
```

Comment: You close the pipe before forking, the child process will be unable to write to it.

Comment: The don't have distinct descriptors ? for example: Parent has his own descriptors and child has his own descriptors ?, are shared bteween processes ?

Comment: @pcCC28 Not until after you fork, there is no child process yet.

Comment: So the child will inherit the file descriptors of parent ?

Comment: Yes. Both the child and the parent will have the same descriptors.

Comment: Your question is unclear because you are trying to present two different versions of the same program in a single program. Please either show the two programs you mean, or rewrite your example with conditional compilation.

Comment: @ritlew True but a bit misleading: After closing a descriptor in one process you are still able to use it in another process that shares the descriptor until it closes the descriptor as well. Its' not the *same* descriptors but copies, isn't it?

Comment: @ritlew: formally, a file descriptor is local to a process, so the parent and the child have separate file descriptors with the same numbers.  However, those open file descriptors _do_ share an open file description (file descriptions are distinct from file descriptors) and the current offset in the file is a property of the file description.  See [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html), [`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html), [`execve()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execve.html).

Comment: I was not familiar with the formalities that you pointed out, but the meaning I was getting at was the same you are presenting here.

Comment: OT:  The function `fork()` has three kinds of returned value: <0 means an error occurred.  That returned condition is not being checked in your code.  When calling most of the C library functions always check for an error indication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct output is certainly not `2`. When you close the pipe before forking, both processes now how a closed `pipe[1]`. When the child process attempts to write to the pipe, it will not be able to. Thus, the parent will read `1`, because `2` was never written to `pipe[1]`.

Comment: If I have:
n=22;
write(p[1], &n, sizeof(int));
close(p[0]);
if(fork() == 0) {
                int r = read(p[0], &n, sizeof(int));
                printf("r = %d\n", n); } .Will work, the read will return 22

Comment: Please see the above example. I have close de read descriptor before fork and the read still working

Comment: That may be because you are attempting to read into a variable that is already 22. So the read is failing, but `n` is already 22. It seems like its working but really you are just printing out the variable you set `n=22;`